# How to get from Detroit to Windsor without taking the Tunnel Bus or a private car?

Tags: international-travel, public-transport, borders, ontario, detroit

I am currently in Detroit and want to get to Windsor in Canada, to continue onwards towards Niagara Falls. I don't have a car. Normally, this is possible by taking the Tunnel Bus, but its service is [currently suspended](https://www.citywindsor.ca/residents/transitwindsor/service-to-detroit/Pages/service-to-detroit.aspx). What other possibility do I have to get there?

I am a German citizen, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Travel to Niagara Falls NY and then walk over?

Comment: Ah, that could work! Do you have any tip on how to do that? All the connections I can find go through Canada.

Comment: Isn't getting into Canada what you're seeking?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I was unclear in my comment. All the connections I can find start from Windsor in Canada, assuming that I can get there by tunnel bus - which is currently suspended.

Comment: Getting to Niagara Falls, NY without going through Canada seems to be surprisingly hard.  The airport has minimal commercial service and, oddly, I haven't been able to find any coach service that stops there.  If you wanted to go this route your best bet might be to fly from Detroit to Buffalo and then take Amtrak from Buffalo to Niagara Falls (three trains daily.)

Comment: It sounds like this is too late for your trip, but for future planners: it seems the tunnel bus [will resume on November 27, 2022](https://www.citywindsor.ca/residents/transitwindsor/service-to-detroit/Pages/service-to-detroit.aspx).

Comment: Could you take an intercity bus?  I've used Greyhound between Toronto and Chicago several times.  It stopped in both Windsor and Detroit.

Comment: @gerrit:  Currently Greyhound doesn't return any results when you search Detroit—Niagara Falls (ON) or Detroit—Toronto.  It won't even let you search for Windsor or Niagara Falls, NY.  There might be some other bus line that would serve these routes, though.

Comment: @gerrit Greyhound ended its intercity service in Canada about a year and a half ago.  A few US routes extend into Canada, but not from Michigan to Ontario.  Coach Canada seems to have a much more limited network that is more oriented towards regional transportation (commuters).  The articles I found online mostly discuss the problems caused by the sudden lack of an intercity bus network and possible solutions.

Comment: OK — even in North America, public transportation can become even worse.  Next try.  Get to Sandusky somehow, then take a [ferry via Pelee Island](https://www.ontarioferries.com/pelee-island-ferries/)?  Oh, doesn't work outside summer :-(

Comment: Thanks for all the contributions and tips! I stood for some time at the tunnel entry, trying to hitch a ride, but finally gave in to the Uber drivers stopping and trying to convince me to pay them. Found one going to the other side anyway, so I was able to pay "only" 40 USD.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The Checker cab company of Detroit](https://www.checkerdetroit.com/canada-border-crossing) advertises taxi service to downtown Windsor.  It does not appear that their web app will allow you to book this service;  you will have to either call them or use their phone app instead.  (I am not affiliated with them, they just come up as an option when one Googles "Detroit Windsor taxi service".)

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Detroit/comments/n7e4au/whats_the_cheapest_taxi_option_to_go_from_detroit/) from one year ago also discusses various taxi options.  According to one poster in that thread, conventional taxis were charging $65 + $2/mile for a cross-border service.

Answer (score 10):

Well, Phineas Fogg. You certainly picked a challenge!

Unfortunately, the 11/9/01 terror attacks had a severe effect on the permeability of our Canadian border. At least in the "Toward USA" direction, which was enough to kill the thru trains, buses and even walking across the bridge.  The good news is it's not bad in your direction, and the US does not have exit controls. So you can just hitch a ride with high hopes of not being turned away at the border.

You might be able to hitchhike across the bridge, or find someone on social media making that crossing anyway who will give you a ride.

### Don't cut the corner. Take Amtrak from Detroit to Buffalo.

It can be said, at least, that this is a sure thing. And paradoxically, it is the cheapest.

As you know, Michigan is a *peninsula*. As such, the major east-west trunk lines don't enter the peninsula, but that's OK - you're only an hour away from them at Toledo, Ohio.

So you book an Amtrak trip from Detroit to Buffalo.  Cost is under $30 depending on date.  Due to low ridership, the Detroit-Toledo segment is an express bus which leaves at 9:30 pm and gets into Toledo probably 10:45 pm give or take.

You are now on the route of the famous *20th Century Limited*. Unfortunately your train will be its little brother *The Lake Shore Limited*. It comes through Toledo around - holy smoke! 3AM.

The ride gets you into Buffalo about 9AM. This is a full-service train with high attendant levels, and they should wake you.

American trains are subject to delay. Many people say bad things about that, but it's simply because these routes are breathtakingly long. The Lake Shore Limited is a "short" one and it's 1543km (Munich-Berlin x3). That means delays only accumulate (stack). This is just something you have to get used to.

Now to get from Amtrak Buffalo to Niagara falls, *wouldn't you know it,* there's an Amtrak train.  But Amtrak's booking engine won't book it on the same ticket. A call to 1-800-USA-RAIL might get it on one ticket.

Comment: "That means delays only accumulate (stack)" That's not really true... If you don't want delays, you put buffer times into your time tables. You have extra trains on stand by that can take over a route if necessary (so when the train from A to B to C is late, then the backup train will depart B on time towards C). It's pretty telling, in some countries, when you are on a train that departs late, there is a good chance you will still arrive on time. In other countries even if the train departs on time you are not likely to arrive on time. Mostly a question of money.

Comment: @nobody easy in theory, harder in practice. You can't leave a station early, and people HATE sitting long times at stations for no reason.  *Pad time that is behind you is like runway that is behind you - useless*. Amtrak's latest trick seems to be to slow down the trains, so they meld better with freight and if they're late they can open it up to regain time.  On the backup train, pencil it out for the *California Zephyr* assuming 2-3 consecutive late trains could happen. How many spare trainsets and crews do you need on standby at Denver, Salt Lake and Oakland?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica you raise good points. However, that's still a scheduling problem. If 9 times out of 10 the train from A to F, arrives F late, the arrival time should have been set at a later time, even if sometimes the delay happen on B, others on C and others on E. And the time that you would have already arrived at F on time, well, you will need to wait (a bit). But that's still better than angry users due to the late train (except for those that arrived late to the station, of course!).

Comment: Similarly, the trains will not be traveling at the maximum speed supported by the engine and track. That would mean that on any slightly adverse meteorological condition, which would force it to slow down, the train would end up delayed. The train will have some margin, which can be used (under good conditions) to regain [part of] the time lost. I remember a case when the train really speeded up, managing to arrive to the station just before hitting a delay deadline which would have made them pay an (higher) reimburse to the users. Something really making them interested on arriving on time :)

Comment: @Ángel historically Amtrak ran at track speed, 79 mph most places due to lack of automatic train stop, but PTC fixed that and track speed is now 80 or 90. Once I was on a late Albany-Cleveland train. Tip top track (but no train stop), dead of night on a Sunday, overpowered train rated for 105 mph. The train Could NOT Be Allowed To Block The Mainline. (relief crew would take hours due to blizzard, which also kept people with radar guns away LOL).  The crew would die in 7.5 hours and the trip was 9 hours. Well... I awoke near Rochester, that *was not* 79 lol. Trip took 7 hours.

Comment: So in that case it was "the crew going dead and blocking the busiest mainline in the east" that put the fear into the operator.  In that case all our delays were at the departure (frozen toilets). I personally think that's the best answer; have a (legal) speed reserve.  I think Amtrak is doing that since they haven't tightened the schedule after getting 79->90. However having ridden many transcon trains, delays are an almost unsolvable problem. Stuff just happens. Really, America needs national HSR and pay for it by accepting priority freight also. The freight lines are totally saturated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I also came across the train option after some persistent googling around directly before I had to leave. Unfortunately, It didn't fit my schedule at all due to the timing of the trains and so on, otherwise I would have liked to try it! In the end I gave hitchhiking over a shot, but the only ones who stopped in about an hour were Uber drivers trying to take me for payment. Which is what I ultimately did.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a driver's license, it appears that you can [rent a Zipcar in Detroit](https://www.zipcar.com/detroit) and [drive it across the border to Canada](https://support.zipcar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485367-Can-I-drive-my-Zipcar-outside-of-the-country-). Note that you cannot leave the Zipcar in Windsor, however, as [Zipcar](https://www.zipcar.com/en-ca/cities) does not operate there.

You should be able to drive both [in the U.S.](https://www.fodors.com/community/europe/german-drivers-license-in-the-us-1009879/) and [in Canada](https://canada.diplo.de/ca-en/consular-services/08-OtherConsularServices/drivers-licence/1154326) with a German driver's license.

Comment: Zipcar also doesn't do one-way rentals.  You have to return the car to its home location.  So even if your ultimate destination is Toronto or some other place where Zipcar does operate, this won't help unless you are planning to return to Detroit.

Comment: OP didn't say they were planning to stay in Canada.

Comment: I was reacting to "Note that you cannot leave the Zipcar in Windsor, however, as Zipcar does not operate there."  You can't leave the Zipcar anywhere other than where you picked it up from, regardless of whether Zipcar operates there.